# Allow non-admin users to created CouchDB databases

Tags: authentication, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm using CouchDB 2.1.0 and for my use case I would like non-admin users to be able to create their own databases that they will then have write/read access to, and the ability to add other users with write/read access.

Note that this is not one database per user, which seems to be the common use case, but many user-created databases per user.

Users are being created right now by `POST`ing to the `_users` database. Authentication is being handled by CouchDB's built-in authentication.

I *could* create a backend service that has admin credentials that would create these databases, but I would like to avoid doing so. Reading through docs it seems like by default CouchDB only allows admins to create databases; is there a way to change this?

Comment: I have been looking into that pretty intensely lately, I am pretty sure creating a backend service to perform this is the way to go

Comment: Has any of you worked around this? I'm about to go with the intermediate backend idea...

Comment: I never found a way to work around it; ended up creating a backend service which was kind of a bummer but it's really basic (basically just a proxy to a CouchDB with an admin account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I think the only real answer here is that you'll have to make a backend service that has admin credentials that can create new databases. Kind of a bummer since one of my goals for this project was "no backend other than CouchDB".

My backend service ended up just taking a list of users that should have access to the created database, creating the database with a unique ID, and returning that ID. I then have a document in each user's DB that lists all of the DBs they have created.

Comment: Any chance you'd be able to share a 'hello world' server that hears a browser request, passes it on to Couch, and then returns a result back to the browser?